# Angular4 intercepting http errors

Tags: angular, http, interceptor

I wrote an Angular4 http interceptor. It works fine for the request and for non error responses. But I'm not able to intercept an 401 for instance, the interceptor isn't even triggered. Does someone have an idea how to intercept an 401, for instance to forward to the login page?

Here is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { PersistenceService, StorageType, IPersistenceContainer } from 'angular-persistence';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()

export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    storageContainer: IPersistenceContainer

    constructor (
        public persistenceService: PersistenceService,
        public router: Router
    ) {
        this.storageContainer = persistenceService.createContainer(
      'org.ptnc.auth', 
      {type: StorageType.SESSION, oneUse: false}
    )
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        req = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.storageContainer.get('jwt')
            }
        })

        return next.handle(req)
        .do(event => {
            if(event instanceof HttpResponse ){
                console.log('intercepts the response', event)
                // this.router.navigate(['/auth/login'])
            }
            if(event instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
                console.log('the real error')
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: As with other errors in observables, you need to implement `.catch`.

Answer (score 1):

If `HttpClient` throws an error for a response it bubbles up through the observable chain.

You have to use `catch` on the `next.handle(req)` observable to catch and handle the error coming from the `HttpClient`:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // ...
    return next.handle(req)
      .do(event => {
         // ...
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle the error;

        // rethrow it
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a part of my http.service.ts

```
  get(request: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(`${this.actionUrl}${request}`)
      .map(res => this.extractData(res))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    return res.json();
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.log('Error', error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
```

Hope it helps as well

Answer (score 1):

To intercept `HttpErrorResponse` using `HttpInterceptor` you have to make it in the `rxjs` way using `do` operator.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

return next.handle(req).do(event => {
    console.log('handle success event');
    return event;
}, error_event => {
    console.log('handle error event, ie 404 or 500');
    return error_event;
});
```

**Note:** catch didn't did the trick for me because http errors are not firing errors with `throw()`